Pdo sqlsrv. unable to connect (login timeout expired) to microsoft Sql Server on php 8 and Rocky Linux 9
I got a cPanel installed on Rocky 9 Linux and I need to connect to SQL Server 2019 from PHP (8.1).
I installed the driver using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=redhat18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#redhat17
Connection code:
//config
$ip = "xxxxx";
$port = "1433";
$database = "xxxxx";

$user = "xxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxx";


//$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=$ip,$port;Database=$database;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=yes"; //tried that to - same effect
//$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server='$ip','$port';Database='$database'";//and with brackets - same
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=$ip,$port;Database=$database;";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$conn -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

I got:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC
Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired in
/home/bartoszw/public_html/db_test_105.php:48 Stack trace: #0
/home/xxxxx/public_html/db_test_105.php(48):
PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server='...', 'xxxx', 'xxxx') #1 {main}
thrown in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/db_test_105.php on line 48

On the server side, I use above user in microsoft sql management studio and I connect ok (from machine itself, and others too. So it's not firewall on the serwer side as far as I am aware)
Any idea?

I use above user in microsoft sql management studio and I connect ok (from machine itself...SQL Management Studio does not run on Linux, so you cannot be using it from the same machine where your PHP code is situated. Therefore, there could easily still be a firewall issue preventing you from connecting between the Linux machine and the SQL Server. It could be an outbound firewall on the Linux machine, or an inbound firewall on the SQL Server machine, or maybe even SQL Server is not set up to accept external connections at all.

However, since the error is specifically a login timeout, this suggests that actually the PHP script did make an initial connection to the SQL Server, but that it timed out at the next step, which is the login handshake. This could be due to poor performance on the SQL server, or a poor network connection, or a DNS issue, or - according to my online research, this even can sometimes occur if you provide the wrong credentials, or if your username or password contains any unusual characters which are then not escaped properly. So there's some stuff for you to investigate.

See also here

You need to specify login info, because i guess you didn't setup kerberos on linux

That's a good point - is the SQL Server login account you're trying to use a Windows Authentication account or a native SQL Server account?

@ADyson - Means server machine (windows server)

@siggemannen  Commented19 i guess you didn't setup kerberos - I dont Know what that is, so I will read

@baron_bartek Kerberos is what Windows Authentication is based on. Most likely your Linux server users are not enabled for this, and/or the Linux server is not joined to your Windows domain. If that's true, then trying to connect from your Linux server to a Windows SQL Server using Windows Authentication is not going to work. Use a SQL Server native login instead.

II have figured this out. I left the port blank and It connected. Final connection string I used: sqlsrv:Server=$ip;Database=$database;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes . So thanks everyone for their input

That's pretty weird. 1433 is the default port anyway

At least you fixed it though

Yes its weird because I did not set up non standard port.... it did not cross my mind this could be it. Anyway I'm happy it works. Thx.

I left the port Blank and I got connected:
Final connection string I used:
sqlsrv:Server=$ip;Database=$database;Encrypt=no;TrustServerCertificate=yes
I don't understand it why default port was the problem (and why no port at all works?) Machine (sql) as far as I know has standard configuration. Maybe somebody knows?
